# Can I perform an action if a notification gets touched?

Tags: android, push-notification

I have seen a demo of a phone performing an action when a notification on the top of the screen gets pulled down. Usually when you do this on Android the notification menu opens. It works with all apps, so not only from specific supported apps. I have tried implementing this, but couldn't find any way to do this.

```
.addAction
```

only allows me to add buttons, but not something like this. Ideally, I think I would need to implement something like an onTouchEvent into all notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Following code create a notification, if you add an intent to it (in my case it is empty) an action can be performed when notification is clicked.

```
 public void buttonClick(View v){
        final Intent emptyIntent = new Intent();
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyActivitity.this, 0, emptyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("My notification")
                        .setContentText("Hello World!")
                        .setAutoCancel(true) //when clicked it disappears
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent); //Required on Gingerbread and below

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) MyActivitity.this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: Indeed, but what about other types of interactions? Like dragging the notification?

Additionally, this only works if my app creates the notification, which is not the case.